# okhttp and facebook crashed

Tags: android, picasso, okhttp

I am using picasso framework for displaying images. I have used facebook and dropbox as social network to download images.

If i hit dropbox and show images and and within displaying images i hit facebook it crashed with single logcat issue
   **fatal signal 11 (sigsegv) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 15224 (asynctask #1)**

I have read and got to conclusion
 1. there is no out of memory.
 2. some this is causing to using some space which is unavailable

On seaching for okHTTp
 it hits services in secured soket in Trasport layer. If the same time some one use trasport layer out side this socket this crashed with fatal signal 11  [see link here](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/issues/90)

My appication uses images and I want to use Piccaso.because UIL through OOMs so much

Any help to solve

**What to solve: OKhttp or picasso with facebook or dropboxapi**

Thanks.

Comment: Please post information in the [OkHttp issue tracker](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/437). If you can provide a URL that reliably reproduces this problem, it will help me to isolate and fix.

Comment: This question is linked from the following Cordova issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7925 (File Transfer plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my issues with crashing facebook interaction by following official workaround :

> URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new OkHttpClient());

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to SSL context issues as explored on [this okhttp github issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/184).

The fix is pretty straightforward (copy/pasted from the issue):

```
  OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
  SSLContext sslContext;
  try {
    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, null, null);
  } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    throw new AssertionError(); // The system has no TLS. Just give up.
  }
  okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

Comment: Also try adding this to the end: `URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(okHttpClient);` In my case, this fixed Facebook Audience Network SDK + Cordova giving *SSL_select_next_proto* segfault.